# JavaScript 'onclick' context in class

Tags: javascript

Today I was wondering about the best way to keep context in an `onClick` listener when used inside a class. If **this** was answered somewhere please link me to it... I was obviously too stupid to find it.

Anyway, my question is: Is there a best practice or are some of my ideas stupid or even wrong?

I tried a few things...

```
// THIS is what I normally use for the _this_ problem :P
this.addEventListener('click', event => this.onItemClick(event));


// _this_ is not the class but the item ("wrong")
item.addEventListener('click', this.onItemClick);

// Don't use _this_ but pass it
item.addEventListener('click', event => this.onItemClick(event, this));

// Maybe there is something with function.call(this)?
```

**EDIT:**

One more way thanks to  Nedko Dimitrov & epascarello. **Warning** this will create a new function and you will lose the context to potentially remove the listener: [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)

```
// Method.bind()
item.addEventListener('click', this.onItemClick.bind(this));
```

Nice day

Elias =)

Comment: `'click', this.onItemClick.bind(this)`

Comment: instead of passing *this* as parameter to your function you can: `item.addEventListener('click', event => this.onItemClick(event).bind(this))` or `...call(this)`

Comment: @NedkoDimitrov `this.onClick.call(this)` results in execution when adding the listener `this.onClick.bind(this)` seems to work.

Comment: The one potential downside to using `.bind(this)` inline is that if you need to remove the event listener for any reason you have now lost the reference to the function you added. `Function.bind` creates a new function. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind - So it is usually better to do the binding in the constructor or to assign the new function to a variable.

Comment: @lemieuxster oh... thanks for the heads up... I will add that.

Comment: You'll often see people bind the context in the constructor as well `this.onItemClick = this. onItemClick.bind(this)`

Comment: You can also bind `this` using arrow function for your callback when you define it, `const  onItemClick = (event) => {...};`.

Comment: @DrewReese I prefer to use the `class Bla` with methods approach.

Comment: @Elias Ok, since it wasn't mentioned I was just pointing out that you could use an arrow function to do the binding so your code in not rebinding the function in-line on each invocation and keeping the reference so you remove event listener later.

Comment: @DrewReese oh.. right :D my bad ^^ appreciate your intentions :)

Comment: Inside `class Foo`, use `onItemClick = event => { /* "this" refers to class inside here */ }`. Then you can add and remove the click listener with `item.addEventListener('click', this.onItemClick);`