# Event is losing when passing parameters to bind()

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to bind a `callback` with `event` but it lost the event when passing the `callback`. Here is my codes

**HTML:**

```
<button id="click">click</button>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
<script>
    class T {
        handler (e, c) {
            console.log(e)
            console.log(typeof c)
            //c(e)
        }

        run () {
            document.getElementById('click').addEventListener('click', this.handler.bind(this, e => {
                console.log(e)
            }))
        }
    }

    (new T).run()
</script>
```

When I don't pass the `callback` the `event` is logged correctly. Codes here

```
handler (e) {
   console.log(e)
}

run () {
  document.getElementById('click').addEventListener('click', this.handler.bind(this))
}
```

Now, how can I pass both `event` and `callback` to the handler?

Comment: You bind the callback as the first parameter? It should be `handler(c, e)` if you want to use `bind` like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting both the callbacks and event. Modify your code like this and you would see that your callback is called. Your first argument is the callback and second is event.

```js
class T {
        listener (e, c) {
            console.log(e);
            console.log(typeof c);
   e();
            //c(e)
        }

        run () {
            document.getElementById('click').addEventListener('click', this.listener.bind(this, e => {
                console.log('I am called');
            }));
        }
    }

    (new T).run();
```

```html
<button id="click">click</button>
```

You will see that callback is called and you see 'I am called'.
You should however modify the arguments to name them properly. e, the first param doesn't look like a callback and similarly the second param.

Answer (score 0):

I would not bind a function and instead do: `[..].addEventListener('click', event => this.listener(event, cb))`

See why here: [Event Listener in Class Context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54200923/javascript-onclick-context-in-class)

Answer (score 0):

```js
function handleClickListener(e, callback) {
  console.log('clicked');
  callback(e);
}

function startListener() {
  document.addEventListener('click', e => handleClickListener(e, (e) => console.log(e)));
}

startListener()
```